# How to download FTP Files from Previous date to Current Date

Tags: c#

I can download ftp files from C# but it downloads the current date file. I need to download the files from previous date to current date. For example, my files are:

```
xys04-02-2011.zip xys04-03-2011.zip xys04-04-2011.zip
```

I am trying the following code in console application:

```
string defaultLocalFolder_MCX = "C:\\";

FastZip fzMCX = new FastZip();

fzMCX.ExtractZip(
    defaultLocalFolder_MCX + "\\xys03-31-2011.zip", 
    defaultLocalFolder_MCX, "");

FtpWebRequest requestFileDownload = 
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost/Source/" + fileName);
requestFileDownload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");
requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = 
    (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream();
FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localPath + fileName, FileMode.Create);

int Length = 2048;
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
}

responseStream.Close();
writeStream.Close();

requestFileDownload = null;
responseFileDownload = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you need to parameterize your method by date, and then generate the filename from that date:

```
string formattedDate = date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
fzMCX.ExtractZip(
    defaultLocalFolder_MCX + "\\xys" + formattedDate + ".zip", 
    defaultLocalFolder_MCX, "");
```

Then just call the method in a loop:

```
for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= dateTime.endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    FetchZipFile(date);
}
```

(I just guessed at the name as it's not really clear what's going on with the zip file extraction.)

A few suggestions in terms of code style:

- Use `using` statements for all disposable resources, rather than closing them manually. The includes `WebResponses`.
- Be consistent in your variable naming; typically local variables are named in camelCase rather than PascalCase
- Consider extracting the "copy one stream to another" code to a helper method - or if you're using .NET 4, use `Stream.CopyTo`
- You don't need to set local variables to null at the end of the method; it's pointless and just creates noise in your source code.

Comment: thanks for help,i cant understand how to change the code can you modify the above code of mines and can you send me the complete modified code

Comment: @user691235: I showed you the change you need in the only bit of code you showed us which specified a filename. My guess is that you need to do the same thing for the `fileName` variable, but you haven't shown where that comes from. Which bit of my suggestion do you not understand? There's little point in giving you complete code that you don't understand - it's much better if you follow what I've done and apply it yourself.

Comment: the code is  string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            string filename = string.Format("xys{0}.zip", dateString);
            string localPath = "c:\\";
            string fileName = filename;
            string defaultLocalFolder_MCX = "C:\\";

Comment: @user691235: Well seeing as I've suggested changing the method to accept a `DateTime` parameter, just use that instead of `DateTime.Now`.